# Filter values from a python list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list as such `['1.jpg','222.jpg','333.jpg']`
I have a dataframe with column 'file_name'
is there a way to filter the row using the python list?

I am aware

```
df_filtered = df[(df.file_name == '1.jpg') | (df.file_name == '222.jpg')]
```

But this require handcode each value, rather than using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df_filtered = df[df['file_name'].isin(['1.jpg','222.jpg','333.jpg'])]
```